# Arch Linux: DisplayPort → HDMI

Tags: linux, display, connection, display-adapter

I’ve got a Lenovo ThinkCentre running Arch Linux. It’s connected to a display with a DisplayPort to HDMI cable, which only works sometimes (quite randomly). When it doesn’t, the display remains black, but it does receive a signal. Do you have any idea if this is a hardware, adapter, or software issue?

Comment: Do you have any other monitors? I remember I had a strange issue where a desktop would work with a 1080p VGA and 4K DP setup, but not a 1080p HDMI and 4K DP setup.

Comment: @udlp Unfortunately, I’ve got only one monitor. That’s kind of the problem: I don’t have enough hardware to test everything. But thanks for the tip, sounds like just another instance of adapter foo.

Comment: Assuming you have a passive adapter (which I think you do, since you say it's a DP to HDMI cable), there's *likely* no adaptation taking place. Most DP sources like GPUs and iGPUs support pushing the HDMI protocol over DP, which means, as far as your computer is concerned, you have a simple HDMI to HDMI cable. I say likely, because technically they don't have to support HDMI over DP, but I've yet to find a device that doesn't.

Comment: @udlp Yes, it’s passive. Do you have any good active adapter in mind?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm just trying to rule out what could be the cause, and explaining how DisplayPort is weird. You'll have to wait for someone else to think of the right cause.